# how to mutate()- warning message

Tags: r

New to R.

I am trying to mutate(location2) but it is giving me  warning message:

```
#fix truncated values
DFnew %>%
  mutate(location2 = case_when(
    str_starts(Location, c("s", "S", "S.")) ~ "S. SJ @ Ashley Store", 
    str_starts(Location, c("p", "P")) ~ "Pleasanton @ Ranch 99",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))

Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `location2`.
i longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
i Input `location2` is `case_when(...)`. 
2: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_starts` or any `stringr` function accepts a regex pattern. If you pass a vector it will match first pattern with first value, second pattern with second value and so on.

So try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DFnew <- DFnew %>%
          mutate(location2 = case_when(
                str_starts(Location, "s|S|S\\.") ~ "S. SJ @ Ashley Store", 
                str_starts(Location, "p|P") ~ "Pleasanton @ Ranch 99",
                TRUE ~ NA_character_
          ))
```

Or you can also use `regex()` function with `ignore_case = TRUE` to make the regex case-insensitive.

```
DFnew <- DFnew %>%
  mutate(location2 = case_when(
    str_starts(Location, regex("S\\.?", ignore_case = TRUE)) ~ "S. SJ @ Ashley Store", 
    str_starts(Location, regex("P", ignore_case = TRUE)) ~ "Pleasanton @ Ranch 99",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

Comment: THANKS!, now I want to rename "location2" to "Location" but i don't want to overwrite "NA" values from :location2" to exisiting "Location". I tried using : DFnew <- DFnew %>%
  rename(Location_=Location) %>%
  mutate(Location = case_when(
    str_starts(Location_, c("S. SJ @")) ~ "S. SJ @ Ashley Store", 
    str_starts(Location_, c("Pleasanton")) ~ "Pleasanton @ Ranch 99",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))

Comment: You can use `coalesce` i.e `DFnew %>% mutate(Location = coalesce(location2, Location)) %>% select(-location2)`

Comment: ah that works, how about skipping the step where i create "location2" and just use "Location". Do I have to rename the existing "Location" then coalesce it to the new "Location" ? Thanks

Comment: If you don't create `Location2` then the information from your original `Location` column would be lost and you don't have anything to `coalesce` then.